# Correct way to order interactive data table in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to order my reactive data table in R shiny. The below code creates a datatable based upon two user inputs: (`input$x`, `input$y`). I want the datatable to be rearranged in order by `input$y`. How do I achieve this?

```
    #creates a data table that reacts to the user variable input
     df <- reactive({
     lpop %>%
       select(input$x, input$y)
        %>% arrange(input$x, input$y)     #this is the part that I cannot figure out
       })



      output$mytable = ({DT::renderDataTable({df()})})
```

Do I need to add an order option somewhere in the following code?:

```
output$mytable = ({DT::renderDataTable({df()})})
```

Comment: Apologies, where do I add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
df <- reactive({
  lpop %>%
    select(input$x, input$y) %>% 
arrange_(.dots = input$y)    
})
```

It's a bit odd because for almost all other dplyr verb are the underscore version depricated but for arrange is it still valid.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That you, you've solved the problem :) The only issue is it threw an error when arranged your way. It worked when the pipe before arrange was moved

df <- reactive({
  lpop %>%
    select(input$x, input$y) %>% 
arrange_(.dots = input$y)     #this is the part that I cannot figure out
})